# Mapping variables from 2 lists and storing them in separate data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, mapping, nested-lists, purrr

I have a list of 14 times-series hop trials. 14 with time and 14 with vertical distance, As shown in the list, how would I use MAP instead of a LOOP to pair each respective time and vertical trial as a hop1, hop2, hop3, etc... and put them in a master data frame?

list dt and dv

[image]

a sample would look like this:

```
hop1 <-data.frame(hop =1,t = dt$time_100L_1, v = dv$vertical_100L_1)

hop2 <-data.frame(hop =2,t = dt$time_100L_2, v = dv$vertical_100L_2)
```

and store all of the hops in a master. Can I rowbind the 2 list and put a hop ID on each like in the sample?

I am using this code,

## first map the first element extracted as data.frame/tibble to bind columns to form a new list

```
combined_hop <- purrr::map2(d100Lt, d100Lv, ~data.frame(.x, .y)) %>% 
  # use ldply() as it will use the list names as a column we can use as ID
  plyr::ldply(tibble) %>% 
  # group by this newly generated ID
  dplyr::group_by(.id) %>% 
  # build new group ID (you could build it from your column names
  dplyr::mutate(G_ID = dplyr::cur_group_id()) %>% 
  # ungroup the tibble
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  # select renaming the columns of interest (dropping the intermediate ID)
  dplyr::select(ID = G_ID, TIME = .x, Vertical = .y)
```

it works but I am getting the column id out of order, while the 2nd and 3rd column are correct.
[new data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP4XJ.png)

any suggestions how to get the proper order?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you have two list, where each is a dataframe/tibble and both have the same dimensions. If the columns are in the same order a possible solution would be this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(plyr)

# demo lists
dt <- list(data.frame(a1 = c(1, 1),
                      a2 = c(2, 2),
                      a3 = c(3, 3)))

dv <- list(data.frame(b1 = c(111, 111),
                      b2 = c(222, 222),
                      b3 = c(222, 222)))

# first map the first element extracted as data.frame/tibble to bind columns to form a new list
purrr::map2(dt[[1]], dv[[1]], ~data.frame(.x, .y)) %>% 
# use ldply() as it will use the list names as a column we can use as ID
  plyr::ldply(tibble) %>% 
# group by this newly generated ID
  dplyr::group_by(.id) %>% 
# build new group ID (you could build it from your column names
  dplyr::mutate(G_ID = dplyr::cur_group_id()) %>% 
# ungroup the tibble
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
# select renaming the columns of interest (dropping the intermediate ID)
  dplyr::select(ID = G_ID, VELO = .x, TIME = .y)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID  VELO  TIME
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   111
2     1     1   111
3     2     2   222
4     2     2   222
5     3     3   222
6     3     3   222
```

Comment: So this worked really well. It put the the columns and the rows for each hop, the only weird thing is the identifier column jumps from 1 to 7-14 then back to 2-6...not sure how that works. I ran it a few times and it happened like that each time.  The time and vertical position still match though for all 14 trials

Comment: do you mean ".id" or "G_ID" or both? ( you can keep them both by just omitting the last "dplyr::select()" line and the pipe operator before for comparision)

Comment: the code you provided works but the ID column goes  1,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,2,3,4,5,6 while the time and vertical columns have the correct order. I edited the post and provided a picture with the code you suggested. Brilliant btw. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Map` :

```
result <- Map(cbind, hop  = seq_along(dt), t = dt, v = dv)
```

If `dt` and `dv` are inside a list you can do :

```
result <- Map(cbind, hop  = seq_along(dt[[1]]), t = dt[[1]], v = dv[[1]])
```

Comment: But I need to bind the rows, not the columns. Stack them one on top of the other in three columns. The ID column, Time columns, and Vertical Column in the new data frame. Ive tried it but Im having an error with rbind and the trial names not being the same so it wont bind the rows of the next trial to the columns above with a different trial name thats in dt and dv.

Comment: @AaronSanchez Try doing `result <- do.call(rbind, result)`

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
 do.call(Map, c(f = cbind, c(list(hop = seq_along(dt)), do.call(c, list(dt, dv)))))
```

Comment: Yeah Ive tried this before but I need to bind the rows, now the columns.  When I try to bind the rows I get an error because each succeeding time and vertical have a different trial number so the name error pops up. can I drop the name and just use an identifier column instead?